# Smart Groups - Added contacts show status of 'smart' not 'added'

Tags: smartgroups

I have recently upgraded to 4.6.19 which has solved issues to do with the updating of smart groups. However if I add a contact to a smart group it does not show the status of 'added' but shows the status to be 'smart'.

Comment: Perhaps it maybe related with this [There is some inconsistent/confusing workflow managing contacts from smart groups?](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15416/there-is-some-inconsistent-confusing-workflow-managing-contacts-from-smart-group)

Comment: interesting - i was trying to 'find contacts in this group' in a smart group, and 'smart' is not one of the group status checkboxes. 'added' returned no results. if i unchecked 'added' it turned up.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this in 4.5.5 and 4.7.9 (sorry, don't have a 4.6 test environment) and the status of a contact added to a smart group is indeed "added", so unless it is a bug with your specific version, perhaps the contact you believe to have added actually fit the criteria of the smart group to begin with? In any case, upgrading will resolve the issue.

Kind regards,
Tamar

Comment: I have just got around to testing this in 4.6.19 and it certainly seems to be in error. I have attached a youtube video which demonstrates the issue.

https://youtu.be/D1kYw2lMJW8

Comment: Hi Martin - see if you are able to reproduce the issue on the demo site which is running the upcoming release version (4.7.11 at the time that I write this): http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ - if you are not able to reproduce, then you will know that upgrading your version of Civi will resolve the issue - if you ARE able to reproduce it, then consider creating an issue ticket on JIRA: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa - hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Tamar - I'll try to get that done today or tomorrow.

Comment: Well - I waited for over a minute and the sandbox site didn't respond and seemed as if it had no intention of responding. AFAIK 4.6 is a LTS version  so if the error is showing in 4.6 it would be a good idea to correct it. Unfortunately I am not a developer otherwise I would try to look at the code myself.

Comment: I managed to logon to the sandbox and tried to test the issue above. Unfortunately it is not even possible to create a smart group on the sandbox system. It gives a DB error. I tried using Search Builder and Search and neither allow the creation of a smart group. I think the video that I have already created is sufficient to show that issue exists in the 4.6 LTS environment.

Comment: Not arguing that it exists in the 4.6 environment, but I couldn't reproduce in any of my dev environments so I do believe that the issue will be resolved with an updated version of the system - as I too am no developer, I am afraid that I can be of no further service.

Comment: I was just trying to demonstrate the issue in 4.7 sandbox but it's not possible to create a smart group in 4.7.11 so I seem to be stymied in every direction!

Comment: I was able to create a smart group in the 4.7 sandbox - sorry you had trouble!  Also - LTS doesn't receive non-critical updates, since every update has the possibility of breaking something, reducing stability.